# SpecFlow 2.1.0 nUnit report generation with nUnit 3.6.0 not working

Tags: nunit, specflow

The **SpecFlow** report generation using nUnit is not working as expected.

The expected report should display the results of the execution as well, whereas the execution result is not displayed at all. Instead, only the tests are listed.

I am using the below format to generate the report.

> specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport "C:\Users\Paresh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SpecFlowDemoNUnit\SpecFlowDemoNUnit\SpecFlowDemoNUnit.csproj" /xmlTestResult:"C:\Tests.xml" /out:"C:\Tests.html"

The file *Tests.xml* is generated after executing the tests using 'nunit3-console.exe'.

The versions used:
SpecFlow.2.1.0
NUnit.3.6.0

Comment: Are you running the tests from the command line in order to automate (like Jenkins builds etc.)?

Comment: Yes.. I am running the tests from command line. However, the issue is resolved as I mentioned in the answer. Do you have any idea, on how to generate such SpecFlow reports if the tests are run from Test Explorer window? Again, nUnit 3.6.0 is used for execution.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the SpecFlow report generation with nUnit is probably broken with SpecFlow.2.1.0 and NUnit.3.6.0.

But after using a parameter '**format=nunit2**' while executing the tests via nUnit console, the report generation worked. So finally, the commands used will look like these:

nUnit test execution:

> nunit3-console.exe --labels=All --out=TestResult.txt "--      result=TestResult.xml;format=nunit2" bin\Debug\SpecFlowDemoNUnit.dll

SpecFlow Report Generation:

> specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport SpecFlowDemoNUnit.csproj /out:MyResult.html

Here is the reference link:

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting

Comment: Even though you asked the question, if this is the answer then you should mark it as such for anyone who might run across this in the future (such as myself).  Besides, you'll get a shiny new badge.